How do I insert a row if no rows are returned by a query?
I am trying to create code that will allow user to enter a QUEUENAME. Then if rows are returned in the select statement insert a row with the results. If there are no rows returned I want a row inserted with 'norows' information instead.
When I run the case in Toad there is a syntax error where I have THEN. How can I resolve this syntax error?
SELECT CASE
WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT A.QUEUENAME, DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS, 0, 'ERROR', 1, 'NEW', 2, 'STARTED', 3, 'WORKING', 4, 'DONE', 5, 'RETRY', 6, 'TIMEOUT', 7, 'EDITED', 8, 'CANCELED', 9, 'HOLD', A.SUBCONSTATUS) STATUS, TRUNC(LASTUPDDTTM),COUNT()
FROM SYSADM.PSAPMSGSUBCON A
where A.SUBCONSTATUS in (0,1,2,4)
AND A.QUEUENAME = '&QUEUENAME'
and TRUNC(LASTUPDDTTM) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY A.QUEUENAME, DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS, 0, 'ERROR', 1, 'NEW', 2, 'STARTED', 3, 'WORKING', 4, 'DONE', 5, 'RETRY', 6, 'TIMEOUT', 7, 'EDITED', 8, 'CANCELED', 9, 'HOLD', A.SUBCONSTATUS), TRUNC(LASTUPDDTTM)
THEN
  INSERT INTO NP2DBA.NP2_IB_MSGSTATUS
  SELECT A.QUEUENAME, DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS, 0, 'ERROR', 1, 'NEW', 2, 'STARTED', 3, 'WORKING', 4, 'DONE', 5, 'RETRY', 6, 'TIMEOUT', 7, 'EDITED', 8, 'CANCELED', 9, 'HOLD', A.SUBCONSTATUS) STATUS, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,COUNT()
  FROM SYSADM.PSAPMSGSUBCON A
  where A.SUBCONSTATUS in (0,1,2,4)
  AND A.QUEUENAME = '&QUEUENAME'
  and TRUNC(LASTUPDDTTM) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  GROUP BY A.QUEUENAME, DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS, 0, 'ERROR', 1, 'NEW', 2, 'STARTED', 3, 'WORKING', 4, 'DONE', 5, 'RETRY', 6, 'TIMEOUT', 7, 'EDITED', 8, 'CANCELED', 9, 'HOLD', A.SUBCONSTATUS), TRUNC(LASTUPDDTTM)
ELSE
  INSERT INTO NP2DBA.NP2_IB_MSGSTATUS
  VALUES ('&QUEUENAME','NOROWS',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0')
END
/


use merge https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/de/community/apex/tipps/sql-merge/index.html

"there is a syntax error" - it's generally helpful to give the actual syntax error you get. That is probably "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" here (if you actually have COUNT(*) not COUNT()), because you have WHERE EXISTS ( before the subquery but no closing ) after it and before THEN. It's a bit moot here though as the whole structure is invalid.

CASE is not used for flow control (like IF-ELSE) in Oracle SQL. To perform the desired operation (insert records if they exist, or insert a default value otherwise), you must use a combination of PL/SQL or separate SQL statements with IF or MERGE.

You can't do an insert within a case expression, or indeed within a query.
You could use a PL/SQL block to query whether rows exist, and then decide which insert to perform, but generally PL/SQL should only be used when something can't be done in pure SQL. And a merge doesn't really work here as you want to insert whether or not data exists, and in a different table.
You could do a single insert with a query that unions together your main query and a second query that generates the 'NOROWS' data, either using a NOT EXISTS clause so that only finds a row when the main query won't:
INSERT INTO NP2DBA.NP2_IB_MSGSTATUS
SELECT
  A.QUEUENAME,
  DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS,
    0, 'ERROR',
    1, 'NEW',
    2, 'STARTED',
    3, 'WORKING',
    4, 'DONE',
    5, 'RETRY',
    6, 'TIMEOUT',
    7, 'EDITED',
    8, 'CANCELED',
    9, 'HOLD',
    A.SUBCONSTATUS) STATUS,
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  COUNT(*)
FROM SYSADM.PSAPMSGSUBCON A
WHERE A.SUBCONSTATUS in (0,1,2,4)
AND A.QUEUENAME = '&QUEUENAME'
AND LASTUPDDTTM >= CAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY A.QUEUENAME, A.SUBCONSTATUS
UNION ALL
SELECT
  '&QUEUENAME' QUEUENAME,
  'NOROWS' STATUS,
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  0
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT null
  FROM SYSADM.PSAPMSGSUBCON A
  WHERE A.SUBCONSTATUS in (0,1,2,4)
  AND A.QUEUENAME = '&QUEUENAME'
  AND LASTUPDDTTM >= CAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP)
)

Or as a subquery with a flag in each branch of the union and a FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES clause (12c+) which will stop the 'NOROWS' row being returned if there are any rows in the first branch:
INSERT INTO NP2DBA.NP2_IB_MSGSTATUS
SELECT
  QUEUENAME, STATUS, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MSG_COUNT
FROM (
  SELECT
    1 ROWTYPE,
    A.QUEUENAME,
    DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS,
      0, 'ERROR',
      1, 'NEW',
      2, 'STARTED',
      3, 'WORKING',
      4, 'DONE',
      5, 'RETRY',
      6, 'TIMEOUT',
      7, 'EDITED',
      8, 'CANCELED',
      9, 'HOLD',
      A.SUBCONSTATUS) STATUS,
    COUNT(*) MSG_COUNT
  FROM SYSADM.PSAPMSGSUBCON A
  WHERE A.SUBCONSTATUS in (0,1,2,4)
  AND A.QUEUENAME = '&QUEUENAME'
  AND LASTUPDDTTM >= CAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP)
  GROUP BY A.QUEUENAME, A.SUBCONSTATUS
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
     2 ROWTYPE,
    '&QUEUENAME' QUEUENAME,
    'NOROWS' STATUS,
    0 MSG_COUNT
  FROM DUAL
)
ORDER BY ROWTYPE
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES

fiddle showing both versions running before and after data is inserted. (The data is very made up of course, and as db<>fiddle doesn't support substitution variables, I've used &QUEUENAME as the actual literal queue name, just so it didn't need to be changed in the query.)
I've also simplified the group-by clause, and changed the date/time filter so it doesn't need to manipulate the column value with TRUNC() - which assumes that value can't be before now, which seems reasonable...

I ran this and it only return rows with the NOROWS value. I also need the rows inserted into the table if there are rows returned

The fiddle shows it works both ways, so no idea what is different in your actual data.

You could use PLSQL:
DECLARE
    l_row_count NUMBER;
    l_queue_name VARCHAR2(100) := '&QUEUENAME'; -- Replace with appropriate bind or variable initialization
BEGIN
    -- Check if any rows match the criteria
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_row_count
    FROM SYSADM.PSAPMSGSUBCON A
    WHERE A.SUBCONSTATUS IN (0, 1, 2, 4)
      AND A.QUEUENAME = l_queue_name
      AND TRUNC(A.LASTUPDDTTM) = TRUNC(SYSDATE);

    -- Conditional logic based on whether rows exist
    IF l_row_count > 0 THEN
        -- Insert data for existing rows
        INSERT INTO NP2DBA.NP2_IB_MSGSTATUS (QUEUENAME, STATUS, UPDTIME, ROWCOUNT)
        SELECT A.QUEUENAME,
               DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS, 
                      0, 'ERROR', 
                      1, 'NEW', 
                      2, 'STARTED', 
                      3, 'WORKING', 
                      4, 'DONE', 
                      5, 'RETRY', 
                      6, 'TIMEOUT', 
                      7, 'EDITED', 
                      8, 'CANCELED', 
                      9, 'HOLD', 
                      A.SUBCONSTATUS) AS STATUS,
               CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
               COUNT(*)
        FROM SYSADM.PSAPMSGSUBCON A
        WHERE A.SUBCONSTATUS IN (0, 1, 2, 4)
          AND A.QUEUENAME = l_queue_name
          AND TRUNC(A.LASTUPDDTTM) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
        GROUP BY A.QUEUENAME, 
                 DECODE(A.SUBCONSTATUS, 
                        0, 'ERROR', 
                        1, 'NEW', 
                        2, 'STARTED', 
                        3, 'WORKING', 
                        4, 'DONE', 
                        5, 'RETRY', 
                        6, 'TIMEOUT', 
                        7, 'EDITED', 
                        8, 'CANCELED', 
                        9, 'HOLD', 
                        A.SUBCONSTATUS), 
                 TRUNC(A.LASTUPDDTTM);
    ELSE
        -- Insert default row for no matching rows
        INSERT INTO NP2DBA.NP2_IB_MSGSTATUS (QUEUENAME, STATUS, UPDTIME, ROWCOUNT)
        VALUES (l_queue_name, 'NOROWS', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0);
    END IF;
END;
/


when I execute this I get an ORA-06550: line 16, column 74: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ROWCOUNT": invalid identifier

You'll need to adjust - you didn't supply the table description (the column names are not described).

You appear to be trying to insert into a count column of some type, with count() - which seems odd. You would normally expect coumt(*).
